# JPA 2.0 - Persist child entity automatically on Parent persist, giving org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have two entities named Customer and his Biiling Address. The relationship is one to one. Every customer has exactly one billing address.
I want to persist billing address automatically when customer is persisted.
The customer id is primary key of Customer entity and it is also primary as well as foreign key in address entity.

```
//parent table
public class CustomerDTO implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private Integer id;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="customer_id")
BillingAddressDTO billingAddressDTO;



//child table
public class BillingAddressDTO implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name="customer_id")
private Integer id;
```

This is the code im using to persist entities

```
    customerDTO = new CustomerDTO();
    customerDTO.setFirstName(firstName);

    billingAddressDTO = new BillingAddressDTO();
    billingAddressDTO.setBillingAddress(address1);
    customerDTO.setBillingAddressDTO(billingAddressDTO);
   //persisting customer entity
   customerDAO.persist(customerDTO);
```

I am getting following exception

```
  Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this   
  class must be manually assigned before calling save():
```

I want to assign same customer id to address table so I dnt want to assign it manually. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is so called *derived identifier*. In such an approach the primary key of `CustomerDTO` (parent entity) is shared with `BillingAddressDTO` (dependent entity).

```
@Entity
public class CustomerDTO implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private BillingAddressDTO billingAddressDTO;
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class BillingAddressDTO implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id; // @Column is NOT allowed since id is indicated by @MapsId

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "billingAddressDTO")
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private CustomerDTO customerDTO;
    ...
}
```

In the above scenario the parent entity `CustomerDTO` has a simple primary key `customer_id` and the dependent entity `BillingAddressDTO` shares the single primary key attribute which is mapped by the relationship attribute `customerDTO`.

---

**UPDATE**: alternative solution based on Ali's comment to avoid bidirectional relationship

```
@Entity
public class CustomerDTO implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private BillingAddressDTO billingAddressDTO;
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class BillingAddressDTO implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

In the above scenario the parent entity `BillingAddressDTO` has a simple primary key `customer_id` and the dependent entity `CustomerDTO` shares the single primary key attribute which is mapped by the relationship attribute `billingAddressDTO`.

---

From the underlying database point of view the entities will look as follows:

```
customer_id  firstname
-----------  ---------
          1  Ali Baba

customer_id  billingaddress
-----------  --------------
          1  my_address
```

References:

- JPA 2.0 Specification, chapter 2.4.1: Primary Keys Corresponding to Derived Identities

Comment: Thanks @wypieprz. It works for me but I have a question, please correct me if i am doing conceptual mistake here. Isn't it a logical violation to put Customer(parent entity) in Address(child entity). I think in this way, the relation is bi-directional but we don't need to put Customer in Address as whenever I will need address, I can get it from Customer.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a mistake, but indeed it may be conceptually improper for your needs. I have updated my answer to avoid bidirectional relationship so you can get Address from Customer and Address itself is unaware to who it belongs.